# Change images in UIImageView in sequence

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want make something like animation.

I have four UIImageView (names: IW1, IW2, IW3, IW4)
I want change image in IW1 on image1 and next on image2, after that change image in IW2 on image1 and next on image2, after that change image in IW3 on image1 and next image2, after that change image in IW4 on image1 and next on image2.

Unfortunately when I tried to do this, the only thing I could do is change the images in all UIImageViews at the same time, but I want to do it sequentially.

Someone will help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way

**Header interface**

```
int j;
int i;

UIImageView *imgV1;
UIImageView *imgV2;
UIImageView *imgV3;
UIImageView *imgV4;

UIImage *img1;
UIImage *img2;

NSArray *views;
NSArray *imgs;
```

**Implementation**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    i=0;
    j=0;
    views = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:imgV1, imgV2, imgV3, imgV4, nil];
    imgs = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:img1, img2, nil];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(changeImage) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}


-(void)changeImage{
    UIImageView *imageView = [views objectAtIndex:j];
    UIImage *image = [imgs objectAtIndex:i];
    imageView.image = image;
    i++;
    if(i==2){
        i=0;
        j++;
        if(j==4)
            j=0;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps (I didnt try it)

Comment: Sorry for answer with late. 
Your method is very simple and it is exactly what I want. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)runSwitchImages
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2 delay:2 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        //Animate Image Change Here
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        //When The Image is done animating it will go here

    }];
}
```

You can use something like this to do the changes in series. You can create another one these functions for each images and have them call in series. Or Change the function to be recursive .

If you want it to continue to change us a NSTimer to call the function.

Answer (score 0):

call this somewhere

```
[self performSelector:@selector(changeImage:) withObject:yourImageView afterDelay:1]
```

which will call this after a 1 second delay

```
-(void)changeImage:(UIImageView *)yourImageView
{
     yourImageView.image = yourImage;
}
```